# GlassFIsh4 unable to inject into WebSocket Endpoint

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish-4

I'm trying to use websocket on GlassFish 4, but CDI seems doesn't work for WebSocket.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class WebSocket {

    @Inject
    private TestBean bean;

    ......
}
```

The `bean` will always be `null`.

I have searched google, and find some people saying about the same thing, but nome of the solutions could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this exact scenario working at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/javaee7-samples/tree/master/websocket/injection

What is bean-discovery-mode in your beans.xml ? It should look like:

```
<beans
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
bean-discovery-mode="all">
```